# How to correctly decontainerize the value side of a Pair object

Tags: raku, raku-container

I'm building up several [`Pair`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Pair) objects in a loop, and I use the same scalar variable (albeit with a different value) for the value of each of them.

As a simplified example of what I'm doing, consider

```
my @list;
my $acc = '';

for 1..30 -> $i {
    if $i % 5 == 4 {
        @list.push($i => $acc);
        $acc = '';
    } else {
        $acc = "$acc $i";
    }
}

say @list;
```

(My actual code is, of course, more complicated and reads from a file rather than a predefined range, so I can't simply eliminate the loop altogether like we theoretically could here)

We accumulate strings containing sequences of numbers written out, creating a pair mapping some of the numbers to sequences of values below that number.

I *want* the output of this program to be

```
[4 =>  1 2 3 9 =>  5 6 7 8 14 =>  10 11 12 13 19 =>  15 16 17 18 24 =>  20 21 22 23 29 =>  25 26 27 28]
```

However, I currently get

```
[4 =>  30 9 =>  30 14 =>  30 19 =>  30 24 =>  30 29 =>  30]
```

which, I understand, is because `Pair` keeps the container when I assign a scalar to its value field, so I'm really creating six pairs, all of whose values point to the same (mutable) container.

The documentation indicates this, and it even suggests a way around it

> It is worth noting that when assigning a Scalar as value of a Pair the value holds the container of the value itself. This means that it is possible to change the value from outside of the Pair itself:
>
> ...
>
> It is possible to change the above behavior forcing the Pair to remove the scalar container and to hold the effective value itself via the method freeze

which works. If I replace `@list.push($i => $acc)` with

```
my $pair = ($i => $acc);
$pair.freeze;
@list.push($pair);
```

then the code produces the expected output. Problem is, [`freeze`](https://docs.raku.org/type/Pair#method_freeze) is deprecated, and the only code listed under the deprecation warning as a possible replacement is

> ```
> $p.=Map.=head.say;                                    # OUTPUT: «orange␤»
> ```

which looks like it's converting the `Pair` to a `Map` and then back to do a sort of shallow-copy. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, as `@list.push(($i => $acc).Map.head);` produces the original (incorrect) output.

So, since `Pair.freeze` is evidently deprecated, what is the *correct* way to decontainerize the value size of a `Pair` object in Raku now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are very close.

To get an idea what is going on I put this line `print "$i: "; dd @list;` just before the end of your for loop.

Here's a sample:

```
19: Array @list = [4 => "", 9 => "", 14 => "", 19 => ""]
20: Array @list = [4 => " 20", 9 => " 20", 14 => " 20", 19 => " 20"]
21: Array @list = [4 => " 20 21", 9 => " 20 21", 14 => " 20 21", 19 => " 20 21"]
```

So, as you say, the issue is that the $acc container is just being reused. In your case, you need to set the Pair value to the contents of `$acc`, not to the container itself.

Either of these variants work in place of your push line:

```
@list.push($i => $acc<>);
@list.push($i => "$acc");
```

The decont `<>` operator explictly [decontainerizes](https://docs.raku.org/routine/%3C%3E) the contents of the $acc container.

Or, perhaps more familiar, the `""` quotes produce a new Str value with a copy of the current value of $acc.

Comment: fwiw my vote would be to undeprecate .freeze

Comment: Aha! That's what I was missing. I knew there was an operator somewhere to explicitly decontainerize scalars, but I had no idea how to search for it. Thanks!

Comment: OK - I have added an Issue to undeprecate freeze https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5121

Comment: And a documentation bug report since I think that the search for ```decont``` should be possible without knowing it it ```<>``` in advance